# Tensorflow docker container predictions won't work outside of container

Tags: python, ubuntu, docker, tensorflow

I went through the [Tensorflow for poets Tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Fio2016#0) and then classified my own images, this is all done in the TF docker container provided. The model has a validation accuracy in the mid to low 90's. There is a separate file that makes predictions for new images(below).

I copied the files 'retrained_labels_corn.txt' and 'retrained_graph_corn.pd' and the file holding the code seen below to a directory(and changed the file paths) to see if I could make predictions while not in the docker container. I made sure I give it a valid image path as the system arg but it always predicts the image as one class with a probability above 97%. When I do the same thing while in the docker container everything works fine. I even tried pointing the labeling file to the exact same files that docker container uses and I am getting the same result of it always predicting one class with a high degree of certainty.

What did I do wrong?

```
import tensorflow as tf, sys

image_path = sys.argv[1]

# Read in the image_data
image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(image_path, 'rb').read()

# Loads label file, strips off carriage return
label_lines = [line.rstrip() for line 
               in tf.gfile.GFile("/tf_files/retrained_labels_corn.txt")]

# Unpersists graph from file
with tf.gfile.FastGFile("/tf_files/retrained_graph_corn.pb", 'rb') as f:
graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
_ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

with tf.Session() as sess:
# Feed the image_data as input to the graph and get first prediction
softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')

predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor, \
         {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})

# Sort to show labels of first prediction in order of confidence
top_k = predictions[0].argsort()[-len(predictions[0]):][::-1]

for node_id in top_k:
    human_string = label_lines[node_id]
    score = predictions[0][node_id]
    print('%s (score = %.5f)' % (human_string, score))
```

I am on Ubuntu version 16.04 and TF 0.10

Comment: I am assuming the tensorflow versions are the same.

Comment: yes, tf on docker and the PC are the same version